# using flash with android webview

Tags: android, flash

I want to use flash in webview.

I used following code..

```
 mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
 mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
 mWebView.loadUrl("http://domain-path/flash/test.html");
```

The test.html is containing flash object embedded.

But when I run this it displays nothing.

Please suggest.....

Answer (score 5):

try to add

```
webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
```

Answer (score 0):

it's because you browser doesn't have a flash player. you need to install [flash player 10.1](http://www.omgandroid.com/flash-player-10-1-now-available-for-all-froyo-devices/)

Comment: Thanks sunil, I have installed flash player on my device... but it still displays nothing.... please suggest

Comment: try setting webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); if still no luck then paste you complete code java+html

Comment: I already tired webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); but it not worked....

Comment: here is the code: Java code:

public class flashTest extends Activity {
 WebView mWebView;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://domain-path/flash/test.html");
       
    }
}

Comment: how to install flash player inside android?

Answer (score 0):

I've the same problem. And i've observed that Flash object is embedded but not visible. if i double click the screen, then flash object i can see.

Quick tip: in your html file, set autoplay=true for video, so that webview you can hear the audio.

let me know, if you find the fix already

Answer (score 0):

Have you added permissions to your AndroidManifest.xml?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

I'm always fogetting permissions

Answer (score 0):

First of all be sure to have internet permissions into your AndroidManifest.xml?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

then:

```
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
WebSettings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
webSettings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
```

Answer (score 0):

Chrome for Android will not be supporting Flash. As you may have seen in November, 2011, Adobe announced it has stopped investing in Flash for mobile browsing. Google has long been committed to making the web platform more powerful through open web technologies like HTML5 and is working with Adobe and other partners to further advance the web standard.
You may have to install morzilla for using flash in android