# Embed Html Code that contains video streaming in Android

Tags: android, html, video

I'm trying to develop an Android application which only shows a video streaming embedded as follows:

```
<html>
<embed width="650" height="377 "flashvars="backcolor=111111&amp;frontcolor=CCCCCC&amp;lightcolor=66CC00&amp;autostart=true&amp;skin=http://manage.streamcyclone.com/skins/snel.zip&amp;streamer=rtmp://sc-lb1.streamcyclone.com/janakles_live&amp;file=janakles&amp;plugins=http://manage.streamcyclone.com/plugins/qualitymonitor,gapro-1&amp;abouttext=StreamCyclone Player&amp;aboutlink=http://www.streamcyclone.com/&amp;gapro.accountid=UA-679067-4&amp;gapro.trackpercentage=true&amp;gapro.tracktime=true" wmode="opaque" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" quality="high" name="mpl" id="mpl" style="undefined" src="http://manage.streamcyclone.com/player/player.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></embed>
</html>
```

I've put this html file in the assets folder as "broad.html" and here is my code:

```
public class BroadcastingActivity extends Activity {
WebView engine;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    engine = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_engine);
    engine.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    engine.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true); 
    engine.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true); 
    engine.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false); 
    engine.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false); 
    engine.getSettings().setCacheMode(engine.getSettings().LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    engine.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/broad.html");
}
}
```

I've also set the permission for Internet in the manifest file. But when running. nothing works !!
Any help please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You require Flash for this video to work, for more solutions you can read here: [using flash with android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500121/using-flash-with-android-webview)

Comment: I'm sorry I still can't find a solution. The link you posted doesn't contain a specified one.
Can you tell me how to add Flash to my video to work ?

Comment: That's why I told solutions not solution, you need to have Flash installed in your Android device (which it's not supported beyond ICS) and even then, you need to click in the embedded object to load it (the default behavior is not to load any flash content).

Comment: Thank you. I tried all these solutions but it worked  with me when adding this line engine.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);. It didn't work on the emulator, but on my device.